# How do you name columns based on query results?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is really bugging me.

Is there any way to name both the column (i.e.: [John]) and what you are counting (i.e. 'Bob') based on the results of another query? That way I don't have to define each one manually?

For example, let's say I have the following query:

```
SELECT
   COUNT(CASE WHEN [Name] = 'John' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS [John]
  ,COUNT(CASE WHEN [Name] = 'Bob' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS [Bob]
FROM [database].[dbo].[people]
GROUP BY
   COUNT(CASE WHEN [Name] = 'John' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS [John]
  ,COUNT(CASE WHEN [Name] = 'Bob' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS [Bob]
```

I tried this with a variable, but not having much luck without some type of loop function to loop through assigning variables and definitions right.

Comment: Only with dynamic SQL. Or do the pivoting in your reporting/application layer instead.

Comment: Column names need to be known when the query is executed, so you'll have to create a list of columns and then execute the sql string using dynamic sql. The duplicate has an example of how you'd do this using pivot.

Comment: Oh man, not dynamic SQL!

Comment: I tried dynamic sql once, it killed my dog